# How do i play a song in a media player after i got its path

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

After I get location of the song in the sd card. So how do I use the path, to make a basic music player i.e play button, pause button etc.

Comment: please show us your search  effort and  code

Comment: It is easy, you get a media player, and play the song :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MediaPlayer for it.
Heres a code sample for playing song, here's a tutorial which explains how to do the rest of your need.

To start song:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()
MediaController mc = new MediaController(mediaPlayer);
mc.setDataSource(Path);
mc.prepare();
mc.start();
```

To Pause:

```
mediaPlayer.pause()
```

To Forward:

```
int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
         startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
```

To Rewind:

```
 int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp-backwardTime)>0){
         startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
```